# Prestashop admin in modules tab getting blank page

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I was installed prestashop in my xampp server. When i was open prestashop admin and click on modules tab, i got the blank page.

After this i was enabled error reporting  and getting following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1139 Got error 'this version of PCRE is compiled without UTF support at offset 0' from regexp' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/prestashop/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:91 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/prestashop/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php(91): PDOStatement->execute(NULL) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/prestashop/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(828): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement->execute() #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/prestashop/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Exec/SingleSelectExecutor.php(50): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->executeQuery('SELECT p0_.id_t...', Array, Array, NULL) #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/prestashop/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php(321): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Exec\SingleSelectExecutor->execute(Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Connection), Array, Array) #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/prestashop/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Abstrac in /opt/lampp/htdocs/prestashop/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 3216
```

Please help me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem generally appears when there is a problem with the name of the database.

PrestaShop is successfully connecting to your Mysql server, but it isn't finding a database with the name mentioned in your settings.inc.php.

To isolate the problem:

- Open up PHPMyAdmin for the server in question and run this query:

SELECT * FROM YOUR_DB_NAME.users
If you get a similar error then you know that you've definitely got the wrong database name.

- Make sure that the name of the database on the server matches the case of the database name in settings.inc.php. Depending on your MySQL settings the server may or may not be enforcing case sensitivity on database/table names.

Comment: if i go in the file you're mention i find only this line: <?php
//@deprecated 1.7